# Using functor in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

I've a World datatype that is defined this way:

```
     data World = World
    { resolution :: (Int, Int)
    , direction :: Snake_direction
    , snake_scale :: Int
    , snake :: [(Int, Int)]
    , isStuck :: Bool
    , gen :: R.StdGen
    , food :: (Int, Int)
    , superFood :: (Int, Int)
    } deriving (Read, Show)
```

and I want to use a functor that uses fmap over the snake list which is a paramter of the world datatype. I'm struggling with functor syntax

```
instance Functor (World) where
    fmap f (World) = World {fmap f snake}
```

but the compiler says

```
error: parse error on input ‘f’
```

Comment: A `Functor` requires that `World` should be a higher-order type (so a `data World a = ...`). That is not the case here. Furthermore what do you intend to do with `fmap f snake`, `fmap` over the snake?

Comment: Yes I want to fmap over the snake

Comment: but as said, this only works if `World` is a higher-order type (the kind should be `* -> *`).

Comment: does a monad works as well only if world is a higher order type ?

Comment: yes, `Functor`, `Monad`, and `Applicative`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we inspect the `Functor` type class, we see:

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
  {-# MINIMAL fmap #-}
```

So the *kind* of `f` should be `* -> *`, a type with a type parameter. This is not the case here, so we can not declare `World` an instance of `Functor`. Since the user can use any function `f :: a -> b` to map a `World a` to a `World b`, but there is no `World a` at all.

If you still want to make it a `Functor`, we can first "upgrade" the `World` type such that it has a type parameter:

```
data World a = World
    { resolution :: (Int, Int)
    , direction :: Snake_direction
    , snake_scale :: Int
    , snake :: [(a, a)]
    , isStuck :: Bool
    , gen :: R.StdGen
    , food :: (Int, Int)
    , superFood :: (Int, Int)
    } deriving (Read, Show)
```

then we can define an `fmap` as follows:

```
instance Functor World where
    fmap f w = w {snake = fmap (\(x,y) -> (f x, f y)) (snake w)}
```

or if you want to `fmap` over the `snake` directly, and not over the *coordinates* of the `snake`:

```
data World a = World
    { resolution :: (Int, Int)
    , direction :: Snake_direction
    , snake_scale :: Int
    , snake :: a
    , isStuck :: Bool
    , gen :: R.StdGen
    , food :: (Int, Int)
    , superFood :: (Int, Int)
    } deriving (Read, Show)
```

then we can define an `fmap` as follows:

```
instance Functor World where
    fmap f w = w {snake = f (snake w)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you give me an example of how could I use **Applicative** and **Monad** on the data World a? I'm trying to play with it so I could figure out how it works

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to *not* make `World` a functor, since all you really want is a way to map a function over one piece of a `World` value.

```
snakeMap :: ((Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)) -> World -> World
snakeMap f w = w { snake = fmap f (snake w) }
```

Comment: This is the natural solution here. It doesn't sound like World is a real functor, you just want to map over one of its members.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that this is a special case of an _optic_, and as such can be generated automatically by a lens library.

Comment: I suspected that was the case, but I don't really know enough about them yet to articulate it as such.